# Find structure geometry of $A_1, A_2,...,A_n$ such that $\prod_{i<j} A_iA_j$ is maximum

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, complex-geometry, geometry, inequalities, euclidean-geometry

In any triangle we have the well-known inequality:

$$\sin{A}\sin{B}\sin{C} \le \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{8} (1)$$

Signification of inequality (1): *Let three points $A, B, C$ lie on a circle then $AB.BC.CA$ maximum when $ABC$ is an equilateral triangle.*

**Similarly (4 points lie on circle):**

*Let four points $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$ lie on a circle then $A_1A_2.A_1A_3.A_1A_4.A_2A_3.A_2A_4.A_3A_4$ maximum when $A_1A_2A_3A_4$ is a square.*

[image]

**Similarly (n points lie on circle):**

*Let $n$ points $A_1, A_2,....,A_n$ lie on a circle then  $\prod_{i<j} A_iA_j$ maximum when $A_1A_2...A_n$ is a n-regular polygon*

**[In Three-dimensional space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-dimensional_space):**  *Let four points $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$ in a sphere then $A_1A_2.A_2A_3.A_3A_4.A_4A_1$ maximum when $A_1A_2A_3A_4$ is a [regular tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron)*

**[In Three-dimensional space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-dimensional_space):** *Let eight points $A_1, A_2, A_3,...,A_8$ in a sphere then $\prod_{i<j} A_iA_j$ maximum when $A_1A_2\cdots A_8$ is a [cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube)*

[image]

> **The question:** Let $n$ points $A_1, A_2,...,A_n$ lie on a sphere (in a Euclidean space with $m$ dimentions, $m < n$) find structure geometry of $A_1, A_2,...,A_n$ such that $\prod_{i<j} A_iA_j$ is maximum

Note that: The question ask by me and Ngo Quang Duong.

Comment: The function $\log$ is "completely monotone" in the sense of Cohn-Kumar-Minton http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.3188 so their results show that the octahedron and the icosahedron are also optimal.

Comment: Are you sure about the cube, though?  Often in such problems some square antiprism does better than a cube.

Comment: Yes, I am sure, Thank Dear Dr. @NoamD.Elkies

Comment: I conjecture that: Let $n$ points $A_1, A_2,...,A_n$ lie on a sphere (in a Euclidean space with $m$ dimentions, $m < n$) then $\prod_{i<j} A_iA_j$ is maximum when structure geometry of $A_1, A_2,...,A_n$ satisfying the conditions if $i-j=l-m$ then $d(A_i, A_j) = d(A_l, A_m)$ for all $i, j, l, m=1, 2, \cdots, n$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question of distributing $N$ points on the sphere so that the product of their mutual distances is maximized is asked in

> L.L. Whyte, Unique arrangements of points on a sphere, Amer. Math.
>   Monthly, 59 (1952), 606-611.

Such points are sometimes referred to as logarithmic points because they
minimize the discrete logarithmic energy
$$E_{0}(\omega_{N})=\sum_{i<j}\log\frac{1}{|x_{i}-x_{j}|}$$
among all point configurations $\omega_{N}=\{x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{N}\}$
on the unit sphere $S^{2}$. They are also known as elliptic Fekete points.

Instead of the logarithmic energy, the minimization can be performed with respect to the Riesz energy
$$E_{s}(\omega_{N})=\sum_{i<j}\frac{1}{|x_{i}-x_{j}|^{s}},$$
where $s>0$. The Thompson problem corresponds to the minimization
 of the electrostatic potential energy when $s=1$.

According to

> P.D. Dragnev, Log-optimal configurations on the sphere, Contemporary
>   Mathematics Vol. 661 (2016)

the Whyte problem is rigorously solved for the following 7 values of $n$ *only*, namely,

- $n=1,2,3,4$ : solutions are the ``trivial'' ones
- $n=5$ : two points at the Poles and three points forming an equilateral triangle on the equator (P.D. Dragnev, D.A. Legg, and D.W. Townsend 2002)
- $n=6$ : regular octahedron (A.V. Kolushov and V.A. Yudin 1997)
- $n=12$ :regular icosahedron (N.N. Andreev 1996)

For large values of $n$, the numerical determination of optimal points is difficult as
 the number of local minima grows exponentially with $n$. Designing a fast algorithm to compute in polynomial time “nearly optimal” logarithmic energy points is Problem #7 in Smale's list of problems for this century.

[image]
Configuration of 1600 points and Voronoi cells, near optimal with respect to the $s$-energy for $s=1$ (Image by R. Womersley from this [paper](http://www.ams.org/notices/200410/fea-saff.pdf))

Comment: I conjecture that: Let $n$ points $A_1, A_2,...,A_n$ lie on a sphere (in a Euclidean space with $m$ dimentions, $m < n$) then $\prod_{i<j} A_iA_j$ is maximum when structure geometry of $A_1, A_2,...,A_n$ satisfying the conditions if $i-j=l-m$ then $d(A_i, A_j) = d(A_l, A_m)$ for all $i, j, l, m=1, 2, \cdots, n$.