# An inequality on cyclic polygon defined by Newton's identities

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, inequalities, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Let $n$-regular polygon $X_1X_2\cdots X_n$ with the circumcribed circle $(O)$. Let $n$ points $A_1, A_2,\cdots,A_n$ lie on the circle $(O)$. Let $x_{ij}=X_iX_j$ (for $1 \le i<j \le n) $. Let $a_{ij}=A_iA_j$ (for $1 \le i<j \le n)$.

Now we denote:

$\{ x_1, x_2, \cdots ,x_{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}} \}=\{x_{ij}, 1 \le i < j \le n \},$

$\{ a_1, a_2, \cdots ,a_{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}} \}=\{a_{ij}, 1 \le i < j \le n \}.$

**Conjecture that:**

$p_k(x_1,x_2, \cdots , x_{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}) \ge p_k(a_1,a_2, \cdots , a_{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}})$ for all $k=1,2,...,n-1$

$e_k(x_1,x_2, \cdots , x_{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}) \ge e_k(a_1,a_2, \cdots , a_{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}})$ for all $k=1,2,...,n$

Equality holds iff $A_1A_2 \cdots A_n$ is n-regular polygon.

Here $p_k$ and $e_k$ are the pơer sum and elementary symmetric functions, respectively [see Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).

See also: [My previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248997/find-structure-geometry-of-a-1-a-2-a-n-such-that-prod-ij-a-ia-j-is)

> **My question:** Could you give a proof, or a reference, or a counterexamples?

Answer (score 2):

See if your claims are contained in 
http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/~fpsac/FPSAC07/SITE07/PDF-Proceedings/Posters/82.pdf

Comment: I am not sure, but I think it is not proof. It is a reference.

Comment: Because your reference both sides are the same $(x)$, but this question left side is $(x)$ and right side is $(a)$