# Distributing $N$ points on the sphere so that the sum of their mutual distances is maximized?

Tags: inequalities

Generaliation the result in [our paper](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304456/an-inequality-of-a-cyclic-polygon) for sum and similarly my [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248997/find-structure-geometry-of-a-1-a-2-a-n-such-that-prod-ij-a-ia-j-is?rq=1) for product. I have a question:

**My question:** *Distributing $N$ points on the sphere so that the sum of their mutual distances is maximized*?

[image]

Comment: why not just put $N/2$ points on the North pole and $N/2$ points on the South pole?

Comment: Nice question !!!!

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker For n=4 the tetrahedron is better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually an open problem, the only proven optimal configurations I have found are the [universal configurations](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0607446.pdf) with N=1,2,3,4,6,12, and the [dipyramid](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.0937.pdf) with N=5. Some work for N=7 is done [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1977-31-140/S0025-5718-1977-0478006-1/S0025-5718-1977-0478006-1.pdf), which is compatible with [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20140903233038/http://constrained-geodesic.com/sphere/sphere.htm). Some bounds are given in the paper [Sums of distances between points of a sphere](https://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/Volume5_4/650584.pdf).